# Test search results without increasing bounce rate for my own website?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, bounce-rate

Reading [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/122412/is-it-a-good-practice-to-make-login-reset-password-register-page-indexable/122425#122425) made me curious: if going from the SERP to a website, and then coming back to the SERP counts as a bounce against that website, is there a sure a way to test search queries involving my website among other websites in a way that won't increase the bounce stats for my website? (And ideally not for those other websites too.)

I would think if I do this from an account that has my website added to Webmaster Tools, the search engine *may* recognise I may be testing and won't count, but

1. I may specifically want to be testing using the Private Browsing aka Incognito
2. I wouldn't want to risk it anyway

Comment: Related: [Does a site's bounce rate influence Google rankings?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13920/does-a-sites-bounce-rate-influence-google-rankings)

Comment: Question...if you are just testing how your site is appearing in the SERP, why are you clicking on it? You should know by the URL presented what page is showing. I wouldn't think there is a need to actually click on the result....